# Multi-language configuration of Elasticsearch for 30 languages, wild-formatted product numbers and name

Tags: elasticsearch

we are currently building a multi-lingual product catalog where we index product names and product numbers like this one for about 30 languages (western and eastern-Europe languages, no asian language).

> 561720 - TSC 55 Li 5,2 REB-Plus-FS    Akku-Tauchsäge

The challenges here are:

- 30 different languages
- accented characters with need normalisation
  like ä->ae and ä->a
- composite words like "Akku-tauchsäge"..should be searchable as "Akku-Tauchsäge" or "Akkutauchsäge" or "Akku Tauch Säge" etc.
- product numbers like "561720" should be searchable
- A search for product number like "TSC 55 Li 5,2 REB-Plus-FS" should be supported fairly well...such string may contain '/' or ',' or '-' as separators..search without without separators should be supported
- the search scenario is a typical find-as-you-type functionality where the user is allowed to enter almost anything with the expectation to receive reasonable results.

At the moment with index all product catalogs by language in dedicated indexes with dedicated mappings with dedicated language settings like

```
{
    "properties": {
        "label": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "analyzer": "##LANGUAGE##"
        },
        "caption": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "analyzer": "##LANGUAGE##"
        },
        "text_normalized": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "##LANGUAGE##"
        }
    }
}
```

`##LANGUAGE##` is replaced during the import with the name of the related ES analyser.

In addition to the raw text we inject also normalised versions of the text with accent normalisation (e.g. the German analyser does handle the ä->ae replacement properly).

On the query side we perform in general the following steps:

- split the query string
- perform a substring search for each query term (all combined using end)

The approach works fairly well but the handling of edgecases like the different separators in a term like "TSC 55 Li 5,2 REB-Plus-FS" does not feel done right. In particular we implemented this only for German at the moment...most other languages are likely very similar but I am not sure if there is a better solution that would make the configuration more out of the box instead of rewriting queries or injecting normalised text versions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, just a hint (this is really a vast topic)

This is a tricky topic and requires a lot of time getting right. 30 languages is pretty ambitious to be honest :-)

You might want to take a look at this awesome blog post https://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/ - which just deals with german language but might give you a first hint.